# Android App , how to communicate between Activity, Service and SyncAdapter

Tags: android

Hi Im working on an android app which works both online and offline. So if its connected to wifi , when i click on save button in the Activity , there are multiple requests (StringRequest) sent to server to update the db. And if offline it saves the data to sqlite and once wifi is available, it automatically syncs the data using SyncAdapter. My problem is there is lot of redundant/duplicate code - one for Activity and one for SyncAdapter and i'm trying to cleanup the code. The only difference between the both for each StringRequests in Activity , Response.Listener & Response.ErrorListener  shows some alerts in the Activity and in SyncAdapter it just logs the messages. 
Now i have written a Service class that can be used by both activity and syncadapter , the question i have is how can i send alerts/updates to activity in the Response.Listener & Response.ErrorListener , without breaking the flow of service methods.

private void Method1 () {

```
    if (NetworkConnection.isNetworkAvailable (this))
    {
        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, AppConfigURL.API_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse (String response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            Utils.showLog (Log.INFO, AppConfigTags.SERVER_RESPONSE, response, true);
                        } else {
                            Utils.showOkDialog (MainActivity.this, "Custom alert message", false);
                        }
                        Method2();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
                        Utils.showLog (Log.ERROR, AppConfigTags.VOLLEY_ERROR, error.toString (), true);
                        Method2();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody () throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {

                JSONObject sendJSON = db.getOfflineSavedOrderDetails();

                String str = "{\"API_username\":\"" + Constants.api_username + "\",\n" +
                        "\"API_password\":\"" + Constants.api_password + "\",\n" +
                        "\"API_function\":\"updateSavedFixedDetails\",\n" +
                        "\"API_parameters\": " + String.valueOf(sendJSON) + "}";
                Utils.showLog (Log.INFO, AppConfigTags.PARAMETERS_SENT_TO_THE_SERVER, str, true);
                return str.getBytes ();
            }

            public String getBodyContentType () {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strRequest);
    } else {
        Method2();
    }
}

private void Method2 () {

    if (NetworkConnection.isNetworkAvailable (this))
    {
        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, AppConfigURL.API_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse (String response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            Utils.showLog (Log.INFO, AppConfigTags.SERVER_RESPONSE, response, true);
                        } else {
                            Utils.showLog (Log.WARN, AppConfigTags.SERVER_RESPONSE, AppConfigTags.DIDNT_RECEIVE_ANY_DATA_FROM_SERVER, true);
                        }
                        Method3();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
                        Utils.showOkDialog (MainActivity.this, "Connection Error: My custom error", false);
                        Method3();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody () throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {

                JSONObject sendJSON = db.getOfflineSavedOrderDetails();

                String str = "{\"API_username\":\"" + Constants.api_username + "\",\n" +
                        "\"API_password\":\"" + Constants.api_password + "\",\n" +
                        "\"API_function\":\"updateContractDetails\",\n" +
                        "\"API_parameters\": " + String.valueOf(sendJSON) + "}";
                Utils.showLog (Log.INFO, AppConfigTags.PARAMETERS_SENT_TO_THE_SERVER, str, true);
                return str.getBytes ();
            }

            public String getBodyContentType () {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strRequest);
    } else {
        Method3();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code your JSON as strings. That is what JSONObject class is for and Volley JSONObjectRequest uses that.

Comment: My question is, the service should be working on method1, method2, method3 so on ... but method1 should show a dialog/alert in the Acivity..